# Should an explicitly defaulted constexpr ctor allow non-constexpr initialization

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, default-constructor

I just stumbled upon the following differences between GCC and Clang concerning an explicitly defaulted constexpr ctor and some inheritance...

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  constexpr A() = default;
  T v;
};

struct B : A<int> {
  constexpr B() = default;
};
```

GCC immediately rejects the code while Clang allows to instantiate non-constexpr versions of both types. My guess is that Clang is probably correct, but I'm not 100% certain...

Comment: initialize `A::v` and gcc will be happy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem boils down to:
is a constexpr constructor that default-initializes
some non-static data member of builtin type valid,
if it is not used?

---

**tl;dr**:

- For a non-template constructor,
  no, it is invalid to leave any non-static data members uninitialized.
- For a template constructor, yes,
  it is valid to have some (but not all, no diagnostic required)
  instantiated template specializations
  for which the instantiated constructor does not meet the requirements
  of a constexpr constructor.

In this case, GCC is right, whereas Clang is wrong.

---

GCC gives the following error message which is very informative:

```
prog.cc:8:13: error: explicitly defaulted function 'constexpr B::B()' cannot be declared as 'constexpr' because the implicit declaration is not 'constexpr':
    8 |   constexpr B() = default;
      |             ^
prog.cc:3:13: note: defaulted constructor calls non-'constexpr' 'A<T>::A() [with T = int]'
    3 |   constexpr A() = default;
      |             ^
prog.cc:3:13: note: 'A<T>::A() [with T = int]' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
prog.cc:4:5: note: defaulted default constructor does not initialize 'int A<int>::v'
    4 |   T v;
      |     ^
```

[<kbd>live demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TBFpqf6kawVd9EPu)

Note that the error is raised on the constructor of `B`,
instead of that of `A`,
whose constructor is merely "not usable as a `constexpr` function
because [the] defaulted default constructor
does not initialize `int A<int>::v`."

---

Per [[dcl.constexpr]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#4):

> The definition of a constexpr constructor shall satisfy the following
>   requirements:
>
> - the class shall not have any virtual base classes;
> - each of the parameter types shall be a literal type.
>
> In addition, either its *function-body* shall be `= delete`, or it
>   shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - [...]
> - **every non-variant non-static data member and base class subobject
>     shall be initialized** ([class.base.init]);
> - [...]

Here, `v` is of type `int`, and is not initialized.
Therefore, it seems that the constructor of `A`
cannot be declared `constexpr`.

However, [[dcl.constructor]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6) says:

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function
>   template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy
>   the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor,
>   that specialization is still a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a
>   constant expression. If no specialization of the template would
>   satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor,
>   the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Therefore, the constructor of `A` that is declared `constexpr`
is actually valid,
even when instantiated for `T = int`!

---

The problem is the constructor of `B`.
`B` is an ordinary class (as opposed to a class template),
and for its constructor to be (merely) *declared* `constexpr`,
`A<int>` must have a `constexpr` constructor,
which is not the case.

Therefore, this code should be rejected, as GCC does.

---

(Note that both compilers reject initialization of such a type,
for example:

```
A a{};
B b{};
```

The above code is rejected by both compilers.)

As mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085013/should-an-explicitly-defaulted-constexpr-ctor-allow-non-constexpr-initialization#comment98808747_56085013),
initialize `A::v` and GCC (and the standard) will be happy.